# Program crashes when trying to free a 2D dynamic allocated array

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

In general it is difficult to understand what and why is happening. 
In the beginning of the program I declare two 2D dynamic arrays (all the arrays used in the program have the same dimensions):

```
int **initial_array;
int **new_array;
```

Then I allocate the necessary memory:

```
//dynamic allocate arrays (1st Dimension)
initial_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int));
new_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int));

//check if the memory has been allocated correctly
if (initial_array==NULL || new_array==NULL) 
{
    printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
    return 1; //return with failure
}

for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    //dynamic allocate arrays (2nd Dimension)
    initial_array[i] = calloc(P, sizeof(int));
    new_array[i] = calloc(P, sizeof(int));
}
```

I then call a function that takes the values of the initial array, generates another 2D dynamic array, which I print (inside the function) and free (by calling another function) without a problem, and I store this array to the new_array:

```
new_array = create_new_array(some_data, initial_array);
```

Then I store the values to the initial_array:

```
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for (p=0;p<P;p++)
    {
        initial_array[i][p] = new_array[i][p];
    }
}

free_array_in_function(new_array);
```

So far so good. The problem comes when I free the arrays. The initial_array works perfectly:

```
//free memory
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    free(initial_array[i]);
}

free(initial_array);
```

Then, I try with the new_array but the program crashes:

```
//free memory
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    free(new_array[i]);
}

free(new_array);


ERROR: Unhandled exception at 0x102d12b4 (msvcr90d.dll) in Genetic_v1.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefee8.
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

```
//Function
int **create_new_array(double *some_data, int **individuals_table)
{
      int **children;

     //dynamic allocate array of children (1st Dimension)
     children = calloc(N,sizeof(int));

     //check if the memory has been allocated correctly
     if (children==NULL) 
     {
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
        return 1; //return with failure
     }

     for (cv01=0;cv01<N;cv01++)
     {
        //dynamic allocate array of Individuals (2nd Dimension)
        children[cv01] = calloc(P, sizeof(int));

        //check if the memory has been allocated correctly
        if (children[cv01]==NULL) 
        {
           printf("Error allocating memory!\n"); //print an error message
           return 1; //return with failure
        }
    }

    //Do some calculations

    return children;
}
```

Comment: In create_new_array you are doing any memory allocation. Can you post that??

Comment: @ Karthikeyan.R.S I just post it in the question.

Comment: In free_array_in_function you are freeing the memory??

Comment: @ Karthikeyan.R.S yes I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your first allocation is wrong

```
initial_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int));
new_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
initial_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int *));
new_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int *));
```

most likely you are trying this code on `64bit` OS, otherwise it could have worked acidentally.

Also you overwrite the pointer `new_array` you don't need to this

```
new_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int));
```

or this **inside the `for` loop**

```
new_array[i] = calloc(P, sizeof(int));
```

since you have this

```
new_array = create_new_array(some_data, initial_array);
```

And finally comment

```
free_array_in_function(new_array);
```

because you are freeing the same pointer twice. And when you try to access the arryays in

```
free(initial_array[i]);
```

you are dereferencing a pointer that was already free'd.

That is not how pointers work, once you `calloc` the first time you have a `pointer` i.e. an integer value which represents a virtual addrees to memory, if you `calloc` again and assign to the previous pointer, then you overwrite the address and thus cause a memory leak.

Then you `free` the pointer you allocated with the `create_new_array` function, but you can't `free` the first `calloc`ed pointer since you have lost the reference to it.

Comment: if you will explicitly initialize the array use `malloc` instead of `calloc`.

Comment: This would be the syntax of the malloc no? I think that the calloc is like this. In any ways, I tried it but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @kat please post your `create_new_array` function.

Comment: I should change also the second allocation, because you all give me the same solution, but I have the same problem.

Comment: @kat also what is `free_array_in_function`?

Comment: a function to free the array in the function: create_new_array

Comment: Ok, if I understand well I should not free the pointer inside the function, correct? - For the part that you say that I do not need to do the second allocation 'new_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int));' i am a little bit lost. By calling the function for the creation of the array I automatically reserve the necessary memory?

Comment: @kat Exactly, you are not so lost. And since you overwrite the poitner, then you `free` it twice. Once in `free_array_in_function` and then you try again in the `for` loop, hence the `segmentation fault`.

Comment: So if I understand corrctly the problem is this function: 'void free_array_in_function(int **children) 
{
    int cv01=0;

 for (cv01=0;cv01<N;cv01++)
 {
  free(children[cv01]);
 }
 free(children);
 }' So I should omit it correct?

Comment: You should, and also remove the first `calloc` of `new_array`.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH... for your patience, your time and help!

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(int)` is not same as `sizeof(int *)`. Even sometime it might be same depending on the platform you need to use `sizeof(int *)` here i.e. allocate memory to hold your pointers first.

For your

```
int **initial_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int *));
int **new_array = calloc(N,sizeof(int *));
```

Later you need to allocate memory for your pointers individually.
Now you should have :

```
initial_array[i] = calloc(P,sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

In `free_array_in_function(new_array)`you are freeing the memory that is the reason you are
getting the error. The reason you are freeing the memory twice.